# In a dataframe, how to write a string in one column based on conditions in another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, accounting

I have an accounting trial balance (tb) in excel that I loaded as a df in python.
The df has an index column on the left, starting with 0.
column 1 is the account name, column 2 are the debits, and column 3 are the credits.
Each row is an account with either a debit or credit balance. 
The tb has a "totals" row at the end, with the totals for debits and credits in columns 2 and 3. The debit and credit totals equal each other.

I would like to create a new "account #" column and give each account a number. These numbers should be from 1 to however many accounts there are, up to and not including the totals row. The account # in the totals row should be blank.

I wrote the following for loop, but it continues to assign an account number in the totals row:

```
for i in df['Account']:
    if i == 'TOTAL':
        df['account #'] == ''
    else:
        df['account #'] = df.index + 1
```

What can I do to have the account # for "totals" be blank?

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
import numpy as np 

df['account #']=np.where(df['Account']=='TOTAL', '' , df.index+1)
```